# "td" before "for" loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, beautifulsoup

I was going through a code that parses columns in an HTML file using `beautifulsoup` which had the following lines:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html)
all_tds = [td for td in soup.findAll("table", bgcolor="#ffffff")]
```

I am newbie to python. I couldn't figure out what the `td` before the `for` loop is in the second line of code. Could somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
all_tds = [td for td in soup.findAll("table", bgcolor="#ffffff")]
```

is a ["list comprehension"](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and is equivalent to:

```
all_tds = []
for td in soup.findAll("table", bgcolor="#ffffff"):
    all_tds.append(td)
```

Comment: A list comprehension is a pretty dumb way to write that though; you could just write `list(soup.findAll("table", bgcolor="#ffffff"))`